# How to get Item web client id in Exchange 2007 using EWS Managed API

Tags: c#, exchange-server-2007, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I have an EmailMessage item saved in Draft folder. I need to open an editing form of it in browser, but cannot found id that is used by web client. In [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.webclienteditformquerystring(EXCHG.80).aspx) there is such property, but it fails with Microsoft Exchange Server 2007. What is alternative?
 Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(new ItemId("someId"));
var alternateId = new AlternateId();
alternateId.UniqueId = message.Id.UniqueId;
alternateId.Mailbox = "somemailbox";
alternateId.Format = IdFormat.EwsId;

var convertedId = service.ConverId(alternateId, Format.OwaId) as AlternateId;
```

And convertedId.UniqueId is what I need;